# DomDocument_object->getElementsByTagName('a'); returning an empty array when there are anchors on the page

Tags: php, html-parsing

I am using PHP's DomDocument class to parse HTML.

When I give it html that has anchors it it and ask it to find all the anchors and store them in an array, it gives me an empty array as if there are no anchors.

Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$domObject->loadHTML($content);
$anchors = $domObject->getElementsByTagName('a');
print_r($anchors); // returns empty array.
```

and $content looks like this:

```
     <p>
        Friend David, I do not think we shall need a call bell as Hello! can be heard 10 to 20 feet away. What you think? Edison - P.S. first cost of sender & receiver to manufacture is only $7.00.[12] Hello, hello! New York, hello!
       </p>
       <a href="http://the-irf.com/hello/hello5.html">Prev</a>
       <a href="hello7.html">Next</a>
       <a href="end.html">End</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the whole html?

Comment: @hek2mgl
That is all the html that is in $content

Answer (score 2):

Where is the `$domObject` being set at? Try this:

```
$matchList = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
    array_push($matchList, $anchor->getAttribute('href'));
}
var_dump($matchList);
```

Comment: Sorry I also had $domObject as an instance of DOMDocument earlier in the code. But I tried your solution and it is still not working.

Comment: Check the other answer for the proper way to parse the `Object` @ArashDonsaliKapoor

Answer (score 1):

Note that the code - after fixing the `$dom` / `$domNode` typo, will not return an empty array. Instead it returns:

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
)
```

Meaning that it has returned an object with private properties only. Therefore it looks empty in `print_r()` output.

However the result isn't empty and [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) implements the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface. So you can iterate through results:

```
foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
    var_dump($anchor->nodeValue);
}
```

A simpler way to just check if the result isn't empty, is to check the length of the node list:

```
echo "The query returned " . $anchors->length . " nodes";
```

---

Here comes a complete example:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <p> 
        Friend David, I do not think we shall need a call bell as Hello! can be heard 10 to 20 feet away. What you think? Edison - P.S. first cost of sender & receiver to manufacture is only $7.00.[12] Hello, hello! New York, hello!
       </p>
       <a href="http://the-irf.com/hello/hello5.html">Prev</a>
       <a href="hello7.html">Next</a>
       <a href="end.html">End</a>
    </body>
</html>
EOF;

$domObject = new DOMDocument();
$domObject->loadHTML($html);
$anchors = $domObject->getElementsByTagName('a');

$links = array();
foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
    $links[] = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
}

var_dump($links);
```

Output

```
string(36) "http://the-irf.com/hello/hello5.html"
string(11) "hello7.html"
string(8) "end.html"
```

Comment: right now what I am doing is using the gerAttribute to get the href of the anchors as that is what I need. I am using the foreach and inside itinstead of var_dump I have `array_push($matchList, (string)($anchor->getAttribute('href')));` and when I try to print $matchList, it is empty.

Comment: @faino
What is the nice catch? I don't get what I am doing wrong as my code is still not working. It is: `$domObject = new DOMDocument(); $domObject->loadHTML($content); $anchors = $domObject>getElementsByTagName('a'); print_r($anchors); // returns empty array.foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
   array_push($matchList, (string)($anchor->getAttribute('href')));
}`

Comment: @ArashDonsaliKapoor check my answer, I've updated my code and it's working on my end.

Comment: @faino I just ran your code apart form the rest of mine and it works. But it is still not working in my code. The code where I need it to work. Would you mind checking it out? It is here: http://pastebin.com/QuhH3D2Y . I would really appreciate it. The DomDocument code starts on line 57.

Comment: It works, but not with the code I am trying to get it to work with / in. Would you mind taking a look at all my code and seeing what I am doing wrong? It is here: pastebin.com/QuhH3D2Y . I would really appreciate it. The DomDocument code starts on line 57.

Comment: It's a problem with the `preg_match` stuff I think. If you add `echo $anchor->getAttribute('href');` to the benning of the foreach loop. Do you see the echoes?

Comment: @ArashDonsaliKapoor you're still using the `$domObject` variable instead of the `$dom` variable. Also, the `preg_match` is causing your problems as it is looking for either "https" or "www" and none of the links in the given HTML have either so the `herf` is not being added to the array.

Comment: And tons of many more problems. And I bet, even if we fix them *all* for you you go ahead and add more crappy code and then come back here and complain it would still not work.

Comment: @faino I'm using $domObject because that $dom is passed to the crawl() function and $domObject is the euivalent of that as it is a parametre of the crawl() function. The regex looks for http://, https://, or www that is to check is the href value is absolute or relative (e.g. index.html ). If it is relative, I convert it to absolute and I then add it to the array.

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r What am I doing wrong? I'm sorry for my code being so crappy. Can you give me 5 things, or any more that you willing, that I am doing wrong so that I can learn and do better?

Comment: Start here: http://www.phptherightway.com/ - most likely the part about the error reporting. In development you have the errors at the highest level, screaming even the slightest problems directly to you. Fix them all. Also write more smaller functions to modularize your code. Less complex code, less problems. Also test your code. If you use a function, read the manual up and down, all parameters, return values and how the error handling is with it etc.

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r Okay, thank you for the help. I will do that. Thank you for helping me become a better programmer.